# How to find which key is from which dictionary in python

Tags: python

(In python) I have two dictionaries which are present in a list . Then i retrieved the non matching keys from the two dictionaries w.r.t comparing keys only.
But now my requirement is how to know which key is from which dictionary

My Code

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2) 
second = dict(b=0, c=3) 
for i in range(1): 
    diff = set(first) ^ set(second) 
print diff
```

Comment: Can you show us how you retrieved those non-matching keys? And why do you need the dictionary from which those keys were retrieved?

Comment: Please provide us some sample input and desired output. 

Also, please mention what efforts you have made.

Comment: first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=0, c=3)
for i in range(1):
 diff = set(first) ^ set(second)
 print diff

Comment: output: set(['a', 'c'])

Comment: @hari, you should edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall help you.
You can edit your code like this:

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2) 
second = dict(b=0, c=3) 
for i in range(1): 
    diff = set(first) ^ set(second)
    key_of_first = set(first) - set(second)
    key_of_second = set(second) - set(first) 
print diff 
print key_of_first
print key_of_second
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Output

```
set(['a', 'c'])
set(['a'])
set(['c'])
```

However, there is not need of `for` loop. It is there just because your code was having it initially.

Comment: Why do you have that `for` loop? It's not doing anything for you.

Comment: For no reason... just added loop because .. hari initial code has a loop.

Comment: Guys Thanks for the help.... now i just want to add something on my question: I have two dictionary which is  present in a list & i have two list like wise. These two list i got from converting two JSON object to dictionary & appending those in lists. These two json object i got by providing two IP address in command line prompt

Now every thing you people mentioned are ok. That means i got all the non matching keys . Right now i want to find which key belongs to which IP address???

Comment: You may ask a separate question. Editing the question after getting a satisfactory answer is usually not considered a nice way. Also if you find a solution which has satisfied your needs then you should mark it as 'Accepted'

Comment: Ok.Thanks vineet . I will do it

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function

dict_one = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict_two = {'b': 2, 'c': 3}

keys_only_in_dict_one = set(dict_one.keys()) - set(dict_two.keys())
print('Keys only in dict_one:', keys_only_in_dict_one)  # {'a'}

keys_only_in_dict_two = set(dict_two.keys()) - set(dict_one.keys())
print('Keys only in dict_two:', keys_only_in_dict_two)  # {c'}

all_non_matching_keys = keys_only_in_dict_one | keys_only_in_dict_two
print('All non-matching keys:', all_non_matching_keys)  # {'a', 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
key="foo"

for i in arr: #arr is the list which contains the dictionaries
   if key in i.keys():
     print(i) # Or print something else
```

Comment: But i dont know how many keys are there & also dont know what are the keys as well

Comment: Well, the key might be in some variable right? It will work then too.

Comment: This is just printing each dict (or something else) if the dict has the specified key in it. BTW, you can just do `if key in i:`; you don't need `i.keys()`.